# What actually limits the speed of a USB flash drive?

Tags: usb, data, speed

My system outputs data through USB which is to be stored in a external memory. But it seems that flash drive is not having that much speed like that specified in USB 2.0 protocol.

**What actually limits the speed of flash drive?**

Comment: Where did you get this average speed from?  And notice your comparison between M**b** and M**B**, which is relevant and changes the magnitude from x24 to x3.

Comment: You also need to clarify whether the flash drive supported USB 2.0 or not, and whether the speed rating for the flash drive was for reading, writing, or some combination of the two.

Comment: David and Joe thank you for your comments. Made some edits as you said. hope now the question is more clear.

Comment: USB 2.0 does not imply 480 Mbps.  There are plenty of full-speed USB 2.0 devices out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of different limitations that come into play when using USB devices:

- The device itself, while it may support USB 2.0 that doesn't mean it will read/write at the maximum speed of USB 2.0 (so device hardware limitations like the flash memory used).
- The USB protocol overhead. While the maximum bitrate in USB 2.0 is 480Mbs the maximum effective bitrate for data is 280Mbs or 35MBs (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#USB_2.0).
- Multiple devices on the same controller. Your computer has a built-in USB hub to allow for more USB ports without adding more (USB) controllers. If another device also uses a lot of bandwidth on the same hub the bandwidth remaining for your USB stick will drop.

Possibly there are more factors in play here but I think I covered the major ones here.

Comment: Limited write (and erase, and to a lesser extent, read) speed of the flash chips themselves can be a factor, too.  Higher speed depends on selecting faster chips from the manufacturing process, and also likely on multiplexing the data across multiple chips.